# Posting to iframe works in Chrome but not IE or FF

Tags: ajax, forms, iframe, file-upload, cross-browser

I have a page with a container that gets different content from an ajax request.  This content has a form that posts data (and a file) to an iframe that is also in this ajax content container.  I can submit the form and it works perfectly in Chrome, but Firefox and IE just sit there like I never clicked the submit button.  I have default security settings on each browser, and don't want to change them for this functionality.  Can anyone see any bugs in my code or process that would cause this?  thanks in advance!

form:

```
<form action='processUploadFrame.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='myForm' target='iframeUpload'>
<input type='submit' value='Upload' />
```

iframe:

```
<iframe name='iframeUpload' frameborder=1 width=750 height=150></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  My HTML 101 has failed me.  Having my submit button in a different table cell than the rest of the form doesn't work in IE and FF, but Chrome is okay with it.  Strange.  A simple javascript submit link did the trick:

```
<a href='javascript:document.getElementById(\"myForm\").submit();'>Submit</a>
```

Here's an article that reminded me about the rules of such:  http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/tables.html